# Found 55 vulnerabilities (1 low, 32 moderate, 21 high, 1 critical)

Tags: angular

```
npm install

removed 1 package, and audited 1819 packages in 30s

100 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

55 vulnerabilities (1 low, 32 moderate, 21 high, 1 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Even after doing npm audit fix no vulnerability was removed. how to make all vulnerabilities to 0.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would read this [blog](https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/) npm audit cannot always fix the vulnerabilities due to the sub dependencies. Often though the vulnerabilities need to be reviewed more carefully because the threat vector is pretty slim